# Gradle sync failed. Fixed coding but keeps failing build

Tags: android-studio, gradle, gson, repository

[I'm trying to build my own Telegram app but I keep getting a gradle build fail error. I tried looking for the gson but this keeps happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e2cX.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you may know `com.google.code.gson:gson` is a dependency which should be declared in the `dependencies` section of your `build.gradle` file **not** where you declared it. You should also consider using `implementation` instead of `compile` since it's been deprecated for a while now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
...
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
}
```